# Make a J2EE application avoid updating the DB

Tags: oracle, postgresql, jpa, jdbc, jta

I have a JBoss 6 application running both EJB and Spring code (some legacy involved in this decision). It should communicate to Oracle and PostgreSQL databases, on demand.
JPA is the way DB operations are done, no direct JDBC is involved.

I would like to do the following: without altering the business logic, to be able to "silence" database updates/deletes from my application, without breaking the flow with any exceptions.

My current thoughts are:

- Set the JDBC driver as read-only from the deployment descriptor - this works only with PostgreSQL (Oracle driver does not support this)
- Make a read-only user on the RDBMS level - it might fill me up with errors
- Make all transactions rollback instead of committing - is this possible?
- Make entity manager never persist anything - set the FlushMode to MANUAL and make sure flush() never gets called - but commit() still flushes everything.

Is there any other concise approach to this?

Comment: One (rather complicated) way of doing it that I can think of: create views for each table with an `instead of` trigger that simply ignores all changes.

Comment: To what purpose though?  Telling a user they successfully entered some data when it hasn't been persisted seems like it will be a problem, as will assigning primary keys and anything else that requires database updates to function.  One possibility is to write your own transaction manager that can check the mode you are in and overrides the commit with a rollback depending on the mode.  Sequences could be used outside the operating transaction and so still function if you needed.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name your approach seems like a winner for me. I made an user that has views with the same name as the original user's tables. Now I just have to dinamically change the datasource user at runtime, which is not at all trivial... still searching for a solution on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My request also includes the need for this behavior to be activated or deactivated at runtime.

The solution I found (currently for a proof-of-concept) is:

- create a new user, grant him rights on the default schema's tables;
- with this user create views for each of the tables, with the same name (without the schema prefix);
- create a trigger for each view that does nothing on insert, update, or delete, using `INSTEAD OF`;
- create a data source and persistence unit for this user;
- inject two entity managers at runtime, use the one that is needed;

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure the application works as on production, work on a replica of the Database. Use a scheduler every night that overwrites the replica DB.